# Alternative to offline THREDDS server

Tags: python, ocean, thredds

I have been using the Python package [opendrift](https://github.com/OpenDrift/opendrift/) to simulate a [Leeway drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeway). For this I was using data provided by a THREDDS server, namely [this link](https://pae-paha.pacioos.hawaii.edu/thredds/dodsC/ncep_global/NCEP_Global_Atmospheric_Model_best.ncd). It appears to be offline, however.
Is there an alternative server that provides the same information or is it possible to download the relevant information as a `.nc` file? Above server does not seem to provide a https-API to download it like others do.

Comment: Have you contacted the data source providers? https://www.pacioos.hawaii.edu/metadata/ncep_global.html?format=fgdc#Distribution_Information

Comment: https://pae-paha.pacioos.hawaii.edu/thredds/catalog/ncep_global/catalog.html?dataset=ncep_global/NCEP_Global_Atmospheric_Model_best.ncd shows several APIs to access data